# One sided limits in the sum of a geometric series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find $\lim_{ r\to 1^-} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^k$ and $\lim_{ r\to -1^+} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^k$

I guess I am confused by the concepts of one sided limits for starters. I understand that you would use the formula $a$/$(1-r)$ but I guess I don't understand what ${ r\to 1^-}$ and ${ r\to -1^+}$ means. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $r\to1^-$: The limit as $r\to1$ with $r<1$.$\qquad r\to-1^+$: The limit as $r\to-1$ with $r>-1$.  Do these definitions help?

Comment: Yes, definitely! so for the first one, would the limit be undefined and the second one, it would be 1/2?

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^k$ for $r=-1$ does not converge to some value.  This can be seen by looking at the partial sums. That said, the limit you specified does give $1/2$.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson you misread the operations then.  The question is not to take the sum of the limit, but the limit of the sum.  \\  Yes, that is correct JxxYsde3